# Check sizes are the same when compiling

Tags: c++, compilation, c-preprocessor

I have a dictionary and an array neither of which change size during the program but could often be extended pre compilation. The number of keys and the array length should always be the same size. Is there a way to check this when compiling as it'd be easy to add the key but not to the array or visa versa?

Comment: Ought to show some code, at least those declarations..

Comment: Some code would be rather helpful.

Comment: I don't know of a `dictionary` type, and in C++ an `array` cannot change sizes ever.  Can you clarify what it is you are doing?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Is `countof()` or `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` not an option? Otherwise I probably misunderstood ...

Comment: Is using the same const value to specify the number of elements in the array and the number of keys not an option?

Comment: Ultimately, this will depend on if the size of the dictionary is explicitly set with a compile-time constant.  You should show us the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to check compile time constants. In C++11 it has been cemented with `static_assert` but it's possible with templates as well.

For example given:

```
enum Key {
  K_Zero,
  K_One,
  K_Two,
  K_NUMBER_ELEMENTS
};

static char const Dictionary[] = { ... };
```

You would do it C++11:

```
static_assert(K_NUMBER_ELEMENTS == ARRAY_SIZE(Dictionary),
              "Keys / Dictionary mismatch");
```

Where `ARRAY_SIZE` is defined as:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
char (&ComputeArraySize(T (&)[N]))[N];

#define ARRAY_SIZE(Array) sizeof(ComputeArraySize(Array))
```

If you are still in C++03 (which is probably the case if you don't know the version), then you ought to be a little more clever and replace the `static_assert` with:

```
template <unsigned M, unsigned N> struct mp_equal;

template <unsigned N> struct mp_equal<N,N> {};

namespace {
  mp_equal<K_NUMBER_ELEMENTS, ARRAY_SIZE(Dictionary)> 
    AssertKeysAndDictionarySizeMatch = {};
}
```

Which will trigger a compile time error if they do not match.

Comment: +1. But you don't actually need to define `ComputeArraySize()`. Only the declaration is enough. And I think, the return should not be `ArraySize<N>`. It should be this : `typename ArraySize<N>::type` where `ArraySize` is defined as `template <unsigned N> struct ArraySize { typedef char (&type)[N]; };`

Comment: That's all good, but unless we know what is meant by "dictionary", it is not an answer.

Comment: @Nawaz: Actually, it's a cheat. A function cannot, normally, return an array. So I just wrap the array into a class and pray the compiler won't suddenly introduced weird padding when none is required. However you're right the definition does not make sense.

Comment: @MichaelPrice: I assume the OP knows what he's talking about when he asks for a compile-time check. It's a leap of faith...

Comment: @MatthieuM. : That is why I use the typedef of the array-reference. You could also do this which doesn't need any struct at all : http://ideone.com/9wVc4

Comment: Is `ComputeArraySize` a reference to a function returning an array of `char`?

Comment: @Xeo: No. `ComputeArraySize` is a function, which returns a reference to an array of size `N`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Ah, okay, thanks. Sometimes, I hate the C++ parsing rules. :/ Template typedefs will make things much easier.

Comment: @Xeo: actually, with C++11 you have `constexpr` which help tremendously here: `template <typename T, unsigned N> size_t constexpr size(T (&)[N]) { return N; }`, and you can ditch `sizeof` and the macro (yeah!)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by dictionary you mean `map` or `unordered_map` there's no immediate way to do it at compile time. You could runtime `assert` in `main` OR you could force the map to be always initialized from an array of pairs, and then `static_assert` that the length of the pair array is the same as your main array.